# python - insert intermediate values into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm new to Pandas and I'm trying to convert my old code to DataFrames and Series. I have the data frame that looks like this:

```
time    data    param
t0      -1      x
t1       0      z
t2      -1      y
t3       1      x
t4      -1      y
```

I need to insert intermediate rows for every 1 to -1 and -1 to 1 transition. This row should contain backfilled *time* and *param*, and the *data* value should be zero.

This is how it should look like after that operation:

```
time    data    param
t0      -1      x
t1       0      z
t2      -1      y
t3       0      x       <-- added row
t3       1      x
t4       0      y       <-- added row
t4      -1      y
```

So how can I achieve this? I guess I can create new DataFrame by scanning original one, row by row, and comparing last saved *data* value with a current one, yielding additional zero when needed. Can you suggest better solutions, avoiding row by row iteration?

**UPDATE**

After reading Primer's answer I have come to another solution:

Reading data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO("""time    data    param
t0      -1      x
t1       0      z
t2      -1      y
t3       1      x
t4      -1      y"""), sep='\s+')
df
```

Find 1->-1 and -1->1 transitions, count them, change index values, reindex with full range to introduce missing rows

```
df.index += (df.data * df.data.shift() < 0).astype(int).cumsum()
df = df.reindex(arange(df.index[-1] + 1))
```

Fill missing values

```
df[['time','param']] = df[['time','param']].bfill()
df.data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

I'm still looking for better solutions. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO("""time    data    param
t0      -1      x
t1       0      z
t2      -1      y
t3       1      x
t4      -1      y"""), sep='\s+')
df['count'] = arange(df.shape[0])
df
```

Setup filters for changes from -1 to 1 and back:

```
d1to_1 = (df.data == -1) & (df.data.shift() == 1)
d_1to1 = (df.data == 1) & (df.data.shift() == -1)
```

Copy the data to new dataframes (to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning):

```
df1to_1 = df.loc[d1to_1].copy(deep=True)
df_1to1 = df.loc[d_1to1].copy(deep=True)
```

Modify the new data according to your needs, changing the counter to ensure new rows are above old ones:

```
df_1to1['data'] = 0
df_1to1['count'] = df_1to1['count'] - 1
df1to_1['data'] = 0
df1to_1['count'] = df1to_1['count'] - 1
```

Concat old and new dataframes, sorting by time and counter, and then reset index.

```
df = pd.concat([df, df1to_1, df_1to1], ignore_index=True).sort(['time','count']).reset_index(drop=True)
del df['count']
df
```

This should produce desired output:

```
  time  data param
0   t0    -1     x
1   t1     0     z
2   t2    -1     y
3   t3     0     x
4   t3     1     x
5   t4     0     y
6   t4    -1     y
```

If you could live with new rows being after old ones then you could skip the `counter` part.